# How to erase Kyocera recovery partition

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot

I'd like someone tell me how to erase the recovery partition in Kyocera phones. The thing is that I need to power it in fastboot mode, and that is the only way, it's only possible if the recovery partition is empty. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kyocera, but doesn't the recovery have an option to reboot to bootloader/fastboot? You won't even be able to delete recovery if you cannot go into the fastboot  mode or else if your device is not rooted.

Comment: Had same problems with an old MTK... I think i ended up using the boot.img to overwrite the recovery.img...

Comment: Singhnsk thanks for your attention. No, the recovery menú have only 3 options and the fastboot mode reboot is not present.

Comment: Zillinium that sound good, and it's that I want to do. Now, how do you can do it without the sideload option or the fastboot mode? This Kyocera's processor is not mtk, it's qualcomm.